# Deploy MEAN application

Tags: azure, heroku, deployment, mean-stack

I just learned the MEAN stack and I locally developed/tested an app. Now, I want to deploy this application to the internet so the world can use it. I don't know how to do this and am lost.

So far, this is what I think is needed. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
1) Purchase a domain (done using Google domains)
2) Find a host for that domain (using Hostgator)
3) Deploy mean app to a cloud service (like Azure, AWS, Heroku, Digital Ocean)
4) ???
5) Fiddle with some settings so the user can access my web app on mydomain.com

What is a recommended cloud service to use? This is my first time doing this so help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can deploy it to Azure, create a Azure VM, deploy mean app to it, then map your domain name to this VM. Then users can access it via your domain name.

Answer (score 3):

**There are a lot of articles on the web already**(why not google first?)!

Here are some:

> **Deploy MEAN**

- [Deploy Your MEAN Stack Apps to Heroku](http://blog.mushfiqweb.com/Fkp3FF)
- [Running Mean.js App on Azure App Services with Continuous Integration and Delivery](https://prmadi.com/running-mean-js-app-on-azure-app-services/)
- [Bossable - MEAN Stack Deploy on Azure](http://www.bossable.com/1413/mean-stack-deploy-to-azure/)
- [John Papa - Deploying Angular on Azure](https://johnpapa.net/deploy-angular-to-azure-vsts-angular-cli/)

  - [Deploying a MEAN App to Amazon EC2 (Part 1)](https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-mean-app-to-amazon-ec2-part-1)
  - [Deploying a MEAN App](https://www.m3webware.com/how-to/deploying-mean-js-applications.html)
- [Stackify - Why Azure Deployment Slots are Awesome and How to Use Them](https://stackify.com/azure-deployment-slots/)
- [[express, angular, mongo, mongoose, deploy, digitalocean, ssh, Heroku, node]](https://github.com/ga-wdi-lessons/deploy-MEAN-app)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use AWS for these kind of stacks and in AWS you can use beanstalk and you don't need to care about management.

> https://aws.amazon.com